# Shared memory between process prime number returning zero at child process

Tags: c, pointers, fork, dynamic-memory-allocation, shared-memory

I'm studying concepts of processes and memory sharing between processes. so I took an example code and I'm trying to adapt it to calculate if a number is prime by memory sharing. The code compiles and correctly returns whether a number is prime or not. however I noticed that in case the number is Primo, instead of printing the number is always coming to zero. where am i going wrong in memory sharing?

thank you very much for the support

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main(){
    
    int i, j;
    int prime;
    int count = 0;
    int *n;
    int shmid;
    int pid;
    
    
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &prime);
    
    if(prime < 0){
        printf("Not a prime number!");
    }
    else if(prime == 0){
        printf("Not a prime number!");
    }
    else{
        shmid = shmget(5, 2*sizeof(float), IPC_CREAT | 0600 );
        
        n = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

        pid = fork();
        if(pid > 0){
            count = 0;
            for(j = 2; j < prime; j++){
                if(prime % j == 0){
                    n[0] = prime;
                    count++;
                    wait(NULL);
                }
            }
            if(count == 0){
                printf("%d Is a prime number!\n", n[0]);
                shmdt(n);
            }   
            else{
                printf("%d Not a prime number!\n", n[0]);
                shmdt(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only write to the shared memory in the event that a number is *not* prime

```
if(prime % j == 0){
    n[0] = prime;
```

when `count` is incremented (possibly repeatedly).

Place `n[0] = prime` somewhere outside the loop, so both branches that test `count` can access the integer via the shared memory.

Or just print `prime` directly, seeing as both the shared memory and fork serve no practical purpose in this program. The child process does nothing except immediately exit. The shared memory is just a copy of existing data.

Note, you are allocating `2 * sizeof (float)` for a single `int`.

Do not forget to remove shared memory segments from the system with [`shmctl`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/shmctl.html), and check the return values of all `shm*` functions for failure.